# IBM bluemix : make POST request from Android and how to handle it in NodeJS

Tags: android, node.js, server, ibm-cloud

I am fairly new to the bluemix mobilefirst paltform and stuck at the point where I need to make post request with some parameters from the android client side. I have searched the documentation but not able to find the required .

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there is more than one way to send POST requests, I'll outline one of them.

In order to see end-to-end scenario you can use the HelloTodo Android sample, which uses node.js based Bluemix hosted backend - https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellotodo.

A POST request in this Android sample is made using Request class, which is part of Bluemix Mobile Services SDK - https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellotodo/blob/master/helloTodo/app/src/main/java/com/ibm/hellotodo/MainActivity.java#L255

Server side implementation depends on which framework you chose to use. The most popular nodejs framework would probably be expressjs - http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method

Comment: app.get('/protected', passport.authenticate('mca-backend-strategy', {session: false}), function(req, res){
 res.send("Hello, this is a protected resouce of the mobile backend application!");
});

This is a nodejs server code for GET request .

Comment: app.post('/protected1', passport.authenticate('mca-backend-strategy', {session: false}), function(req, res){
 var uname  = req.body.username;
 res.send("username" ,uname);
}); 

is not working with error...cannot post

Comment: please help...server side sample code is available which does the POST request handling ??

Comment: leave the passport.authenticate part out for now, just make sure you understand how to handle POST requests. use app.post("/path", function(req, res){ res.send ("OK") })

Comment: http://freelifts.au-syd.mybluemix.net/protected1 
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "name": "A green door",
}

body is showing empty . please help me @Anton