# How to send data using HTTP post to Bluemix?

Tags: java, android, ibm-cloud

I have created an android application in eclipse to record the audio and the audio that has been saved in my SD card. Now, I need to send the recorded thing to Bluemix using HTTP post method. How do I send it and what format should I follow ?

Comment: 1) What have you tried to research / try to do POST requests? Hint: search this site for Android POST http 2) Supported format? Read the bluemix documentation, probably 3) Eclipse has been deprecated for almost a year for Android development

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Duplicate =>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012484/ibm-bluemix-make-post-request-from-android-and-how-to-handle-it-in-nodejs